# Does $\frac1{n^\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^n kX_k$ converge in probability to a non-zero random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence of independent random variables such that $X_n=\frac1n$ with probability $\frac34$ and $X_n=-\frac1n$ with probability $\frac14$ for every $n\ge 1$. I am trying to find whether the sequence $Y_n=\frac1{n^\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^n kX_k$ converges in probability to a non-zero random variable.

I found $E(Y_n)=\frac1{2n^{\alpha-1}}$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y_n)=\frac3{4n^{2\alpha-1}}$, from which I can say $Y_n\to 0$ in probability as long as $\alpha>1$. So if $Y_n$ converges to a non-zero random variable, then it must happen for $\alpha\le 1$. But I could not narrow down this search of $\alpha$. I can see that $X_n\to 0$ in probability but not sure if this helps. Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X'_k=kX_k$. Then $X'_k=1$ with probability $3/4$ and $X'_k=-1$ with probability $1/4$ hence this is a standard application of the weak law of large numbers.